# Multiple users writing to sharepoint list simultaneously, concurrency issue

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to add some data to SharePoint list in SharePoint Foundation 2013. All pages of site collection will try to write to the same list.

When pages are accessed currently, data added to list are corrupted.

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/c#" runat="server">
    public string username = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name;
            static readonly object _object = new object();
    public string CurrentTime;

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SPSite MySite = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPWeb MyWeb = MySite.OpenWeb();
            MyWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            // Fetch the List
            SPList ClientList = MyWeb.Lists["NameOfThePage"];
            lock (_object) {

                    SPListItem itemToAdd = ClientList.Items.Add();
                    itemToAdd["UserName"] = username;
                    itemToAdd["DateVisited"] = prevTime;
                    itemToAdd["TimeSpent"] = duration;
                    itemToAdd["PageName"] = prevPage.Replace(".aspx", " ");
                    itemToAdd["Title"] = Page.Title;                        
                    itemToAdd.Update();                         


                      } 
        }
            }
                                                                                           //ignore          

    }
```

I have tried using `lock()` but it is not giving desired result. I think because `_object` is new instance for each case. Please suggest me how to overcome this.

Comment: What do you mean by corrupted? You are adding item to list and not updating, hence no lock should be required